# Why does the no-cloning theorem imply the monogamy of entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I have seen papers where they mentioned that the monogamy of entanglement can be seen as a consequence of the no-cloning theorem. Could somebody sketch this out?

---

N.B.: I have seen the argument that classically one can achieve as many correlations as one desires with as many parties by creating copies of the initial state. I don't see how this works, we are interested in the correlations with the initial state not with copies of it.

Comment: can you link the specific papers you are referring to?

Comment: @glS see for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0606022.pdf & https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11128-009-0161-6.pdf and references therein.